# How to apply a single function to different combinations of attributes from a list of objects?

Tags: python

Given the following class:

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self, numerator1, denominator1, numerator2, denominator2):
        self.numerator1 = numerator1
        self.denominator1 = denominator1
        self.numerator2 = numerator2
        self.denominator2 = denominator2
```

I've created a couple of objects:

```
objects = [Example(1, 2, 2, 1), Example(1, 2, 2, 1)]
```

Now I want to perform the same operation to each of the two pairs of numerator/denominator combinations:

```
sum(m.numerator for m in objects) / sum(m.denominator for m in objects)
```

To try and stay in keeping with DRY I'd like to create a single function to perform this operation and simply change the numerator and denominator combinations each time. Something like:

```
def standard_func(numerator, denominator, objects):
    return (sum(m.numerator for m in objects) / sum(m.denominator for m in objects)

comb1 = standard_func(<numerator1>, <denominator1>, objects)
comb2 = standard_func(<numerator2>, <denominator2>, objects)
```

I can't figure out how to get the above example to work as the `sum` function needs to know that the numerator or denominator is associated with an `Example` instance.

I've experimented with incrementing class variables however I have a for loop that generates multiple iterations of the `objects` list and I want a unique sum of num/denom per list. I suppose I could reset the class variable total on each loop - maybe this is one solution?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do, but when you have variables that have similar roles to the point that you give them identical names with different indices, it's a good sign that you should have used a list or dict instead. So, something similar to `self.denominators = [denominator1, denominator2]` would probably be a good start.

Comment: What's the point of having class objects only to override their attributes when doing processing with them?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - think your idea may work thanks! Will try it out and report back

Comment: @martineau - I'm not sure what you mean when you say "override"?  I'm not changing anything with the processing? In this case I'm simply looking to perform a sum?

Comment: Guess I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish…

Comment: @martineau - appreciate you trying :) Marcus below has nailed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to use `getattr()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string). In your case, this would look like:

```
objects = [Example(1, 2, 2, 1), Example(1, 2, 2, 1)]
def standard_func(numerator, denominator, objects):
    return sum(getattr(m, numerator) for m in objects) / sum(getattr(m, denominator) for m in objects)

comb1 = standard_func("numerator1", "denominator1", objects)
comb2 = standard_func("numerator2", "denominator2", objects)
print(comb1, comb2)
```

Output:

```
0.5 2.0
```

Comment: Fantastic! This perfectly solves the question :) It was so simple too!